# Change theme to snap App

Tags: themes, snap

I want change theme to a snap app because the default one is horrible. I have tried like the following:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark  /snap/leafpad/current/usr/bin/leafpad
```

and it changes the theme but I have the same if I run

```
/snap/leafpad/current/usr/bin/leafpad
```

without anything. I have tried with other theme but it always show the same.
Then the question is: how to change theme on snap software ?

That command does not work and I want change the app theme, how to do that ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to change the theme, you provide a command that does change the theme, and then with your second command "you have the same". You my want to clarify your specific  problem: use "edit" to update your question.

Comment: @vanadium I find my question very clear: How to change the app theme ? Because the gtk variable does not work.